# how to get current date and time in visual studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, systemtime

I am trieng to get the current date and time in my website. I am using the following function to get date and time.

```
Response.Write( DateTime.Now.Date );
```

I am getting the date properly but for the time I am getting as 12:00 AM . Please someone tell me how to get the current time along with the date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `DateTime.Now` and it will give both the current date and time.

By calling the additional `.Date` property, you are getting a date and time with the time portion set to midnight ([as documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx)).